# What is the correct way to use async httpx client with langchain for OpenAI?

Tags: python, asynchronous, openai-api, langchain, httpx

While trying to invoke Langchain runnables asynchronously using `ainvoke()`, facing Attribute Error.

Following the snippet

```
llm = OpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct", async_client=httpx.AsyncClient(verify=False))
prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["text"],
    template=template,
)

runnable= prompt | llm

result = await runnable.ainvoke({"text": text})
```

Facing this error `Attribute Error: AsyncClient doesn't contain the method create()`